# BS4 - float 1st column to right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap4, I need to float the first div column to right in medium devices and up while on mobile it is shown first. It was possible in bootstrap3 having the structure like this below, but since bs4 is now using flex, it doesn't seem to work. Any idea how to achieve this?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 float-right">
         //RIGHT BANNER HERE
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        //SOME CONTENTS
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Both divs on the row are col-12, are you sure this is what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You don't need extra CSS.**

In Bootstrap 4 the `row` is `display:flex`, therefore you can use `d-md-block`(`display:block` on md and up) to override the `display:flex` in the `row`.

```
<div class="row d-md-block">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 float-right">
         //RIGHT BANNER HERE
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        //SOME CONTENTS
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

https://www.codeply.com/go/jjs8RFfwpX

Answer (score 0):

The `.row` comes with `display:flex;` by default, you can override them using an `!important` to cancel the effect.

```css
.row{display:block!important;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-8 float-right">
         //RIGHT BANNER HERE
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
        //SOME CONTENTS
    </div>
</div>
```

ps: see full size output

Comment: Why add extra CSS? `d-md-block` is `display:block`.

Comment: Using !important directly is not a wise choice, I'm with @Themes.guide on this

Answer (score -1):

The HTML structure on the example seems odd, you are using **col-12** in both containers. I assume you want the banner to be on the right and not float around, just to be there, why don't just change a bit your HTML.

Something like

```css
html {
    padding: 20px;
}

.banner, .main {
    border: solid 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 col-md-10 main">
        // SOME CONTENTS
    </div>
 <div class="col-4 col-md-2 banner">
        // RIGHT BANNER HERE
    </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if that works for you

Comment: Hi, I'm gonna have to downvote this. The structure was supposed to be responsive "mobile-first".  what I needed was that the right_banner shall take full 12 columns and is seated above the main_content when it is on xs to sm viewports. Therefore it is necessary to have it declared above the main content with col-12. same goes for the main_cont with col-12 and is below the right_banner. @zim's answer should be the implementation for this.

Comment: I recommend you to clarify this sort of things in the question, since nothing you mentioned here is in the original question. Downvoting the question until is updated.